# strange message when using pgAdmin III

Tags: pgadmin

I am maintaining databases via pgAdmin III. In most operations, a dialog comes up all the time.

[image: this dialog]

It is so annoying and I have no clues about it, any helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename in your error message (`._pgrouting.control`) looks like a Mac resource file, probably put there by a Mac browsing this directory.

Try to remove this file (and any other files startting with "._").

Answer (score 0):

It works!

start > run > cmd

cd to that path (with ._pgrouting.control inside)

notepad ._pgrouting.control
delete everything inside then save

thank you mivk, day saved!